# Ellipsis with apostrophe?

Tags: interpretation, ellipsis, lyrics, apostrophe, figurative-language

This is a strophe from one song:

> "But the times were hard, Lord,
>   the jobs were few
>   all through Tecumseh valley
>   but she asked around
>   and a job she found
>   **tending bar at Gypsy Sally's**"

Can I rewrite that this way:

"tending bar at Gypsy Sally's bar"

Comment: But I don't think there is an ellipsis (something 'missing'). Just like *I work at the butcher's.* Or: *I went shopping at Penny's*. While *Penny's* is a short form of the name of the department store JC Penny, I would not understand any of these sentences in terms of an ellipsis, but rather in terms of natural possessive forms to indicate a place. In fact *Gipsy Sally's* doesn't have to be the name of the bar; it could be the name of the house or place where there is a bar. @StoneyB may analyze differently, though.

Comment: In other words, *I'm going over to Joe's*, there is nothing missing from the sentence, nothing elided. It is this use of the apostrophe that tells us we are referring to a place. Whereas you could say that *We used Jane's car not Bill's* does have an elision of "car" at the end. But (to me) *We went to Jane's, not Bill's* does not involve elision.

Comment: Note that in English LitCrit we call a section of a song or poem like this a *stanza*; *strophe* is reserved almost exclusively for descriptions of Classical Greek dramatic poetry.

Comment: @pazzo Quite right. If you wanta be really cute, you could call it a 'fused-head determiner'. And in fact, Gipsy Sally's is a whorehouse.

Comment: How could I be sure that is whorehouse if I could not see the end of the song? Is there any tradition in English about this name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you can never be too sure with song lyrics - since they're open to multiple interpretations - I think this use of the possessive s ('s) is a common trait in place names of businesses, particularly bars or public houses.

> They serve a good beer at Gypsy Sally's (bar).

It is also used to imply "home", when used after an individual's name or family name.

> I'm just going over to the Johnsons' (house).

Additionally, this is often true of professions such as: the butcher's or the baker's.

So, in short, you **can** rewrite the last line like that, in order to understand it, but it doesn't flow so well because of the repetition of bar. As such, I **wouldn't** rewrite it that way.

Comment: @StoneyB Would his dad be The John, then?

Comment: Thanks people. A beginner's mistake (does that <<< apostrophe get me out of trouble?!). I hang my head in shame. I wrote the answer in bed if that's a mitigating factor...